# Understanding number of threads created by app

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, visual-studio-code

I had a crash in my C++ application. Fortunately I enabled core dump. I found that there are at least 60 `[NEW LWP <some number>]` lines in the core dump of following form:

```
[New LWP 1926459]
[New LWP 1926476]
[New LWP 1926368]
[New LWP 1926456]
[New LWP 1926458]
[New LWP 1926530]
[New LWP 1926486]
[New LWP 1926490]
[New LWP 1926477]
```

While debugging in vscode, its call stack also show several of following entries (I have greyed out my application name):

[image]

I have been handed over this application from earlier team recently. This app processes incoming video frames. As much as I understand there are no more than 10 threads in the application as explained by earlier team.

**Q1.** If all these `LWP`s and vscode stack entries are nothing but threads created by app, is app indeed creating several threads? Does vscode indeed creates extra threads in debug mode? If so, does those extra debug threads appear in call stack window? Or all these threads does indeed indicate some bug in my app?

**Q2.** I am unable to proceed debugging since in vscode, a new thread keeps hitting first breakpoint preventing me from getting in deeper calls. How can I only debug call hierarchy in one specific threads?

PS: If I recall it correct I run app from terminal built in cmake release mode while taking core dump. But need to ensure again.

Comment: Some of them are internal threads started by library routines or system functions.  Threads are a very lightweight construct; it costs very little to create a new one and have it hang around, even if it is not called upon to do very much.

Comment: I am unable to proceed debugging since in vscode, a new thread keeps hitting first breakpoint preventing me from getting in deeper calls. How can I only debug call hierarchy in one specific threads?

Comment: Just to be clear, VSCode is not a debugger.  VSCode is an editor.  It can _run_ a debugger, but you could also run the debugger from your sell prompt.  Rather than ask how to make VSCode do this, you should instead be asking how to make your debugger do this.  On Linux, the debugger is GDB.  So I recommend you search for "gdb manual" or similar and read about how to control threads in GDB